# Model Sim - unable to add new files to a project

Tags: verilog, modelsim, intel-fpga

I am trying to add files to a new Verilog project using Model Sim. When I create a new project, I am unable to see the option to add files to the project.

In the project interface, when I select Add New files to the project, unable to see any pop up.

OS: Windows 10 64-bit
Software: ModelSim-Altera 10.1d (Quartus || 13.0)

I have changed my Windows compatibility to Windows 7, as the software supports only windows 7.1 and windows 8.1.

Please give me tips and if any other software is recommendable for windows 10 for Verilog, I welcome your advice.

Answer (score 2):

If you right click in the `Project` tab, you can add files and more.

[image: QuestaSim Screenshot]

You can also use the command line interface:

```
project addfile <filename>
```

Source: Questa Sim (same as ModelSim) Command Reference Manual: http://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_view/134097-modelsim-command-reference-manual-v10-3a